# Qt creator not installed properly on my ubuntu 23.04 pc

Tags: qt-creator

I have installed Qt creator on my pc using the online installer. but when I run the command **qtconfig** in my terminal I get this output:**qtconfig: could not find a Qt installation of ''**
I can create projects with Qt creator and compile and run them successfully, I also have on Icon for it in my application menu. what is the problem?